# python https proxy error code 400, 401

Tags: python, https, proxy

I have a `HTTPS` proxy written in python. All worked until I made the proxy transparent. I redirected `80` and `443` ports to `8888`(the proxy port). Now only requests over `HTTP` works, when I request a `HTTPS` website, I get `400` and `401` errors on the server. Any ideas? When I make a request over `HTTPS`, I see encrypted text on the proxy side(log) and I don't see any `CONNECT` request.

The proxy is at this address: https://github.com/allfro/pymiproxy

But I've changed it a bit to work as a transparent proxy:

```
def _connect_to_host(self):
    # Get hostname and port to connect to
    if self.is_connect:
        self.hostname = self.getheader('host')
        self.port = '443'
        #self.hostname, self.port = self.path.split(':')


    else:
        self.path =  "http://" + self.headers.getheader('host') + self.path

        u = urlparse(self.path)
```

Comment: can you post the proxy code?

Comment: I'm not sure we can offer any useful advice without seeing some code, but you might want to read over this link http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/HTTPS. There is quite a bit of complexity trying to proxy HTTPS, and you may be running into a design flaw in the python proxy code. That article might help

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if this is OT, but how do you **test** your HTTPS over HTTPS proxy?

Python does not support this!

Neither does `curl/libcurl/pycurl` etc.

You may be able to find a browser that supports it though.

Also, I haven't found anything in the linked github code where you listen on an ssl-enabled socket...

Proxy diagrams (shameless plug) https://stackoverflow.com/a/20330304/705086

Comment: I'm running the proxy on a FreeBSD machine, where I've redirected the ports 80 and 443 to the port where the server listens. When I connect to the network with another device, it doesn't work if I don't specify the proxy. It works if I'm using http://mitmproxy.org/, but the problem is that this proxy has some memory leaks.

Comment: In the linked github code, the proxy is wainting for the CONNECT request. Here is the function: https://github.com/allfro/pymiproxy/blob/master/src/miproxy/proxy.py#L171 . But problem is that the CONNECT request isn't send if I made the proxy transparent, so I must find a way to handle this situation. I found a way on HTTP(I get the host from the request headers - on the HTTP are problems, too)  but on HTTPS it doesn't work because I receive encrypted requests.

Comment: If you essentially listen on `:443` (via redirect), you should expect ssl-encrypted traffic. Once you decrypt that, there should be a `CONNECT` command inside. please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/20330304/705086